# GridView Data disappears with a No MessageBox Click

Tags: winforms, datagridview, messagebox

I have a gridview with a delete button. I've added a messagebox with an 'are you sure' yes/no.  The row of data is deleted fine when you click yes, but the gridview data disappears if you click no.

Here's the code for the delete button click:

```
private void gvOrderLines_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    int intOrderID = 0;

    if (e.RowIndex < 0 || e.ColumnIndex != gvOrderLines.Columns["deleteBtn"].Index) return;

    Int32 orderLineID = (Int32)gvOrderLines[1, e.RowIndex].Value;

    DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to delete this item? ","Delete Item",MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

    if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection))
        {

            SqlCommand comm;

            comm = new SqlCommand("del_OrderLine", conn);
            comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@orderLineID", SqlDbType.Int));
            comm.Parameters["@orderLineID"].Value = orderLineID;

            comm.Parameters.Add("@ReturnValue", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                comm.ExecuteNonQuery();

                intOrderID = (int)comm.Parameters["@ReturnValue"].Value;
            }
            catch 
            { 
                //tba
            }
            finally
            {
                comm.Dispose();
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    populateOrderLines(intOrderID); // This repopulates the gv so why is it blank?
    populateOrderTotals(intOrderID);
}
```

Any suggestions?

All the best,
Numb

Comment: What kind of collection/datasource is your DGV bound to?

Comment: How do you bind your data in the populateOrderLines method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put these lines within the `if (result == DialogResult.Yes)` block:

```
populateOrderLines(intOrderID); // This repopulates the gv so why is it blank?
populateOrderTotals(intOrderID);
```

Comment: That did the trick and the penny also dropped as to why. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you, you just taught a new expression in English :) "the penny drops"